# Search for mail content with Mutt

Tags: email, search, mutt

Is it possible in Mutt to search for specific mail content using built-in functionality? Or, as a last resort, how can I configure `grep` to be used in Mutt?

The documentation only mentions the `search` and `limit` functions, which only search headers.

Comment: Additional to the answers below you should note that searching using mutt is very slow, regardless if you use a cache or not. If you frequently need to search I would strongly recommend an indexer such as [notmuch](http://notmuchmail.org/). It's by magnitudes faster than mutt's built-in search.

Comment: Also in addition to the answers, consider looking closely at the configuration variable [thorough_search](http://www.mutt.org/doc/devel/manual.html#thorough-search). If you don't work exclusively with US-ASCII e-mail with no message-encoding, you probably want it *set* for searching to work the way you'd normally expect. (Took me forever to figure *that* out...)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`search` and `limit` can also actually search inside messages, depending on the search patterns you give. From the [Patterns](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/#patterns) subsection of the Mutt reference:

```
~b EXPR         messages which contain EXPR in the message body
=b STRING       If IMAP is enabled, like ~b but searches for STRING on the server, rather than downloading each message and searching it locally.
~B EXPR         messages which contain EXPR in the whole message
=B STRING       If IMAP is enabled, like ~B but searches for STRING on the server, rather than downloading each message and searching it locally.
```

That is, `~b` only searches in the body, whereas `~B` also searches in the headers.

Note that this can be quite slow, since it may have to download each message one by one if they are not already cached. If you have a mutt version greater or equal to 1.5.12, you can cache the ones you are downloading for later use by setting `message_cachedir` to a directory where you want to store message bodies, which can significantly speed up searching them (and the same for headers with `header_cache`).

Comment: Exactly what I searched for, thanks. Does `message_cachedir` put all messages in the cache, or only new ones ?

Comment: @alex_reader Only ones which you downloaded since it was set. If you do a search that includes the body across an entire folder, it should cache that entire folder as collateral.

Answer (score 9):

You can add flags to the search command, to search the body use the search function with
the `~b` modifier. So to search for cheesecake inside your mail bodies:

```
/~b cheesecake
```

Answer (score 8):

Put `~b` in front of your search pattern to search only in the body of mails. For searching additionally in the headers, use `~B`

There are plenty of other patterns  described in the [mutt manual](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/#patterns).