# How to search my email containing some string in email'content?

Tags: email, mailx

The mail command can list email messages stored on my pc.
How to search my email containing some string in email'content?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Search for mail content with mutt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91046/search-for-mail-content-with-mutt)

Answer (score 1):

If you install package: `maildir-utils`. You can search Emails.

```
mu find Alice Bob
```

Will search all Emails, with words `Alice` and `Bob` at every field.

Man-Page: https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/maildir-utils/mu-find.1.en.html